Sort by stock status Wordpress woocommerce
I want to sort products by stock status to ensure that products that are not available will not be on the first pages.
I am using this code but it is slowing the page so much(around 3-5 additional seconds). Query monitor shows that there is slow query to DB. How can I improve speed of this sorting?
function mpod_sort_by_stock_amount( $args ) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $args['meta_key'] = '_stock_status';
    return $args;
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'mpod_sort_by_stock_amount', 9999 );


Have you tried this free plugin: Stock Exporter for Woocommerce? Couple with Wp rocket it works nicely and do not affect speed.

Try with using pre_get_posts instead of woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args

It didn't help.
